# How to restart the conversesion flow in bot composer

Tags: botframework

I used "repeat this dialog" and it is just repeating the same dialog is there any option available in composer by using which I can restart the conversesion flow from beginning.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

You have a few different options for restarting the conversation: you can call 'Begin a new dialog', 'Replace this dialog', 'End this dialog', or 'Cancel all dialogs'. Which you choose depends on the flow of your bot and what your intent is. You can read about the different options under [Dialog Actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/concept-dialog?tabs=v2x#dialog-actions) in the Composer docs.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. I have a similar situation as OP. I don't want to trigger a specific dialog, or repeat the current dialog. What I want to do is re-route the user's utterance in the current dialog to the recognizer so that the recognizer can trigger an intent depending on the user's utterance (as if the user input the message).